# Is there a way to make resolvconf ignore a specific interface?

Tags: linux, networking, dns, alpine-linux

I have a system with multiple internet links, call them `eth0` and `eth2`.  I'm writing a piece of software to select which is the link in use based on some higher-level set of criteria.  One of the things it does when it swaps between internet links is rewrite `/etc/resolvconf.conf` and call `resolvconf -u` to update the DNS configuration.

My `resolvconf.conf` looks like this:

```
# Configuration for resolvconf(8)
# See resolvconf.conf(5) for details

interface_order="lo lo.* db.config dummy0"
dynamic_order="eth0"

name_servers=169.254.169.250

dnsmasq_conf=/etc/dnsmasq/dnsmasq-extra.conf
dnsmasq_resolv=/etc/dnsmasq/resolv.conf
```

I rewrite the `dynamic_order` line to only contain the interface I want to use at the time.  According to the man page, resolvconf uses first the interfaces listed in `interface_order` and then the interfaces listed in `dynamic_order`.  But with the above configuration, `resolvconf -l` still lists information for both `eth0` and `eth2` and `/etc/dnsmasq/resolv.conf` still contains the nameserver information for both interfaces.

Is there a way to tell resolvconf that I don't want it to use a particular interface, even if it has configuration information for it?